# React router V4 - Problems with 2 diff routes on the same page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have the following switch on my router

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path={["/", "/job/:id"]} render={(props) => <Landing {...props} />} />
   /* And some other routes in here */
</Switch>
```

Basically both path '/' and '/job/:id' are displayed on the same landing page, but '/job/:id' is more like a component that is included within that landing page.

In my requirements, the behaviour of the landing page is as follow

- When entering '/' for the first time, it will make calls to fetch the data from backend, and update it on the landing as a list of job elements.
- Whenever a job element is clicked, the job element will expand and it will display the URL as '/job/2838728' (which follows '/job/:id' format) but will not make any call to the backend, despite both routes sharing the same landing page.
- When i collapse / close the job element it should revert back the URL to '/', but it should not make any calls anymore.

This is the code i used to update the URL

```
const updateCatIndex = job => {
    if (job) {
       const { _id } = job;
       history.replace(`/job/${_id}`);
    }
 }
```

And here where my problems are..

- Whenever i click any of the job element, it will not only change the URL to '/job/:id' format but also making calls to the backend again to fetch data. I just want to update the URL and not making any calls anymore.
- I only want to make call on the first '/' when entering the page.. but now whenever i close the job element, reverting the URL back to '/', it will also make calls again to the backend to fetch data.

So my issues are

- How to make it so that calls to the backend are only done on the first time it enters '/' and not everytime the URL changes from '/job/:id' to '/'?
- How to make it so that i change the URL from '/' to '/job/:id' without refreshing or making any calls again to the backend?

Desperately need help on this, and i don't even know where to begin for this..

Comment: anything stops you making 2 new components, e.g. `LandingPageEmpty` and `LandingPageWithJob`, that would both render `LandingPage` with appropriate props and API calls?

Comment: You mean '/' on first time will load the landingPageEmpty and after calling the data, and got the job elements ready, it would hide landingPageEmpty and show landingPageWithJob instead? Sorry if i got the concept wrongly..

Comment: I did not mean that. Looks like I don't understand your business logic, sorry. Hope someone else will be able to help. If not, please try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)